# Swift reading from plist file

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am trying to learn Swift and at the moment. I am trying to create a property list, which holds patterns for game elements positioning. My property list can be seen in the picture below: [image: property list]

I need to do the following: I want to randomly access one of the patterns, like 0 or 4. When I access it, I want to loop through items and read each of the x positions.

So far I have the following code:

```
// Load the plist
let blocksPlist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blocks01", ofType: "plist")
let blocksData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: blocksPlist!)!
let platformPatterns = blocksData["Patterns"] as! NSDictionary
```

I have tried to look for various tutorials on how to proceed and how to read the x value, but I could not find anything I could (successfully) implement to my situation. So basically, my question is: How do I access one of the patterns and then, how do I loop through it, while at each iteration reading the x value?

Comment: Take a look at the code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29590593/3925941

Comment: Your plist seems unnecessarily complicated. Patterns could just be an array, not a dictionary. Similarly it seems that each of the items inside Patterns could just be an array too, or are you planning on adding more values than just "x"?

Comment: Yeah, later I might add more values, such as type of the block, maybe even y coordinate. So I assumed I should start with dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You should really simplify your plist, but:

Get random array
`var randomPattern = platformPatterns[arc4random_uniform(platformPatterns.count())] as! Dictionary`

Get all elements from array and read

```
for item:Dictionary in randomPattern {
    println(item[x] as! String)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you mind giving me some tips on how you would simplify it?

Comment: also, I am getting an error: 'AnyObject' is not convertible to Dictionary <key><value>. This is for the arc 4 random line. Any idea why?

Comment: you need to manually cast it, its very annoying, basically for every object we go through, you need to cast it to a specific class. Did you put as! Dictionary?

Comment: Also, root can be an array containing your entries that you randomly pick. In those entries, have an array of arrays, with the first array holding items and the nested array holding the x and y value.